# Throwing away from dataframe samples that are too close in time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an original pandas dataframe with datetime column `ts`, ordered by this column. I need to build a new dataframe as follows:

1. its first row is the first row of the original dataframe
2. I only add the row from the original dataframe if it at least 5 seconds away from the last row of the new dataframe

There's an obvious way to do this via a `for` loop, but I have a lot of data and I would prefer an pandas-specific way.

As an example, let's say I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [
    '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:03',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:04',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:06',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:08',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:10',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:12',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:15',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:17',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:20'
]})
```

and I expect to get

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [
    '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:06',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:12',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:17'
]})
```

FWIW, one ai chat bot is not able to solve that, and even provided some answers claiming to get the final result, while actually they give an empty dataframe as an output.

**Edit:** the answer should also work if the times are provided with a millisecond granularity.

Comment: What you want cannot vectorized, the process is iterative.

Comment: @mozway the answer below provides something that seems to work at least in a special case

Comment: In a special case yes, but for a generic case you'll have to loop. To make sure I got it correctly, if the `00:00:06` above was `00:00:07.5` then the next group would start on `00:00:15`, not `00:00:12` and there would be no `00:00:17`?

Comment: @mozway I've actually did not understand what was done exactly in the answer, hence I've asked. Does that really has to do with milliseconds? that sounds weird

Comment: Can you provide the expected output if the `6` was `7.5`?

Comment: @mozway

```
    '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:07.5',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:15',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:20'
```

Comment: Then I confirm that the answer below won't work for this logic and that you can't vectorize it

Answer (score 1):

Simply group based on seconds.

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])

print( df.groupby((df.ts - df.loc[0, 'ts']).dt.total_seconds() // 5.5).first())
```

outputs #

```
ts                     
0.0 2022-01-01 00:00:00
1.0 2022-01-01 00:00:06
2.0 2022-01-01 00:00:12
3.0 2022-01-01 00:00:17
```

sample input 2 #

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [ '2022-01-01 00:00:00.010000000', '2022-01-01 00:00:03.000001000', '2022-01-01 00:00:04.010000000',
                          '2022-01-01 00:00:06.000200000', '2022-01-01 00:00:08.000005000', '2022-01-01 00:00:10.002000000', '2022-01-01 00:00:12.000060000',
                          '2022-01-01 00:00:15.005000000', '2022-01-01 00:00:17.000040000', '2022-01-01 00:00:20.010000000' ]})


df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
#print(df)

print( df.groupby((df.ts - df.loc[0, 'ts']).dt.total_seconds() // 5.5).first())
```

sample output 2

```
ts                            
0.0 2022-01-01 00:00:00.010000
1.0 2022-01-01 00:00:06.000200
2.0 2022-01-01 00:00:12.000060
3.0 2022-01-01 00:00:17.000040
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide a bit of explanation, say why do you have `// 5.5`? What would I do in case I needed to subsample not with 5 seconds, but let's say one half of a second? Also, your method does not work if I add some milliseconds to the original timestamps, even if replace `5.5` with `5`

Comment: Simply put 5 in above you will understand..You looking for atleast 5 seconds...When you keep 5 seconds next second after 6 is `11` which is not avaiable to pandas groupy with previouse value which will be 4 seconds(we don't want it). so If we group with higher precession(in our case 5,5) we are strictly saying we need greater than 5 so it will group with next value

Comment: If I tweak the original conditions a bit, unfortunately it does not work
```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [
    '2022-01-01 00:00:00.010000000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:03.000001000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:04.010000000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:06.000200000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:08.000005000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:10.002000000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:12.000060000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:15.005000000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:17.000040000',
    '2022-01-01 00:00:20.010000000'
]})
```

Comment: what do you mean not working? I tried both examples working absoluetly fine...

Comment: see added 2 examples with answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit! `00:00:17.000040 - 00:00:12.000060 < 5 seconds` hence the sample `00:00:17.000040` should be absent from the result, an instead `'2022-01-01 00:00:20.010000000'` should be there

Comment: you haven't mentioned about milliseconds on your sample inputs..pls, update same on question

Comment: Edited, though not sure why would that complicate things. One can always multiply .total_seconds() output by 1e6 and get an integer. The question is how to choose what goes after `//` in your formula